# Y names in violinplot using loops

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to get a pdf with multiple violinplots using a loop.
I manage to create the plots but I did not find how to change the Y axis names or the title according the column name.

My xlab will be the only "conidtion" for all the plots but Ylab and title should to change depending on the variable name

This is an example of the code that I am using

```
Table<-cbind(c(10,20,30,40,50,60),c(20,30,40,50,60,70),c(30,40,50,60,70,80))

Condition<-c("D1","D1","D1","D2","D2","D2")

rownames(Table)<-c("D1_1","D1_2","D1_3","D2_1","D2_2","D2_3")

colnames(Table)<-c("Gene_A","Gene_B","Gene_C")

Table<-as.data.frame(cbind(Table, Condition))

pdf(file = 'test2.pdf', paper = 'special', height = 11, width = 8.5)


loop.vector <- 1:3

for (i in loop.vector) { 
  
y <- Table[,i]

print(ggplot(Table, aes(Condition, y, group=Condition, color=Condition,)) + geom_violin(trim=F) +

geom_jitter(shape=12, position=position_jitter(0.2), color="black")  +

ggtitle(y) +

xlab("Condition") + ylab(y)) 

}

dev.off()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like so. My approach loops directly over the colnames so that the index of the loop can be used as a label. However, in this case we have to make use of `!!sym(.)` to convert the name to a symbol or variable which can be used in the call to `ggplot` or `aes()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
loop.cols <- names(Table)[1:3]
for (col in loop.cols) {
  p <- ggplot(Table, aes(Condition, !!sym(col), group = Condition, color = Condition, )) +
    geom_violin(trim = F) +
    geom_jitter(shape = 12, position = position_jitter(0.2), color = "black") +
    labs(title = col, x = "Condition", y = col)
  print(p)
}
dev.off()
```